# How to change build directory in QtCreator to add a subfolder

Tags: build, cmake, directory, qt-creator

I use QtCreator for doing C++ applications, and I'm looking to set a relative build directory to QtCreator, but I want all those builds to be inside a "builds" folder, and not at the root of the folder, where the projects are.

For example, actual directory:

```
CodingFolder
  - build-test1-Desktop_Qt[...]
  - build-test2-Desktop_Qt[...]
  - build-test3-Desktop_Qt[...]
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
```

Now, I want to have it like this:

```
CodingFolder
  - builds
      - build-test1-Desktop_Qt[...]
      - build-test2-Desktop_Qt[...]
      - build-test3-Desktop_Qt[...]
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
```

But I don't wan't to set an "static" build folder as the default directory. I want the build folders to be created at the same folder where the project is located, BUT inside a "builds" subfolder

Is this possible?

At the options, there's this setting:

Default build directory:

```
../%{JS: Util.asciify("build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}")}
```

I tried to add the subfolder at the directory, like this:

```
     |
     v
../builds/%{JS: Util.asciify("build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}")}
```

But it didn't work, the subfolder wasn't created.
The project I tried with compiled, but no subfolder appeared (or I don't know where it was stored, then).

---

I tried searching before posting this question, but only got how to set an static, specific directory, and I want to keep it relative.
Thanks in advance :)